# NancyFx and angularjs pass init params using $http.get

Tags: angularjs, nancy

On initial load of the page, I am trying to pass a start and end variables to Nancy using an $http.get method like so:

```
  $http.get("/api/sample", {params:{"start": start, "end": end}}).then(function(response) ....
```

On nancy side, I am not sure how to get my parameters start and end.. so this is the question... How can I get my parameters I passed

```
 Get["/api/sample"] = p =>
  {
  var data = p.data;
  // also tried various suggestions and this this.Bind<dynamic>();
  sampleData= Data(data);
  return sampleData;
  };
```

After this, I have a view like so:

```
Get["/testview"] = _ => View["/testview"];
```

and I would like to get my data passed as json like so:

```
Get["/api/sample"] = p => Response.AsJson(sampleData);
```

at the end my sampleData will be shown on my testview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do it like this :

```
Get["/api/sample/{start:int}/{end:int}"] = p =>
{
  var data = FetchData(p.start,p.end);
  return View("testView",data);
}
```

Have a look at the [Wiki](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a big mistake here.

**POST** with data: This is probably what you want. If you are passing data along, that probably means you are modifying some model or performing some action on the server. These types of actions are typically done with POST requests.

**GET** with query string data: You can convert your data to query string parameters and pass them along to the server that way.

```
url: '/api/sample?ids=1,2,3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just adding this as an alternative.

```
  Get["/api/sample"] = p =>
  {
     var myData = this.Bind<SomeModel>();
     ....
  }
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.